# $100$th decimal place of ${(3+\sqrt10)^{1000}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So far, it is observed and proved that

1. There exists unique positive integers $a_n$, $b_n$ such that
   $\bigl(3+\sqrt{10}\,\bigr)^n = a_n + b_n \sqrt{10}$ for any
   positive integer $n$. Also, $a_n$, $b_n$ can be determined
   precisely by binomial expansion.
2. By considering the fact that
   $0 < \bigl(3-\sqrt{10}\,\bigr)^{1000} < 1$ and
   $\bigl(3-\sqrt{10}\,\bigr)^{1000} + 
   \bigl(3+\sqrt{10}\,\bigr)^{1000} = 2a_{1000}$,
   it is deduced that the integer part of
   $\bigl(3+\sqrt{10}\,\bigr)^{1000}$ is
   $2a_{1000}-1$.
3. The $100$th decimal place of $\bigl(3+\sqrt{10}\,\bigr)^{1000}$ is
   equivalent to the unit digit of
   $10^{100}\, \bigl(3+\sqrt{10}\,\bigr)^{1000}$, i.e.
   $$
   \Bigl\lfloor{10^{100}\, \bigl(3+\sqrt{10}\,\bigr)^{1000}} 
   \Bigr\rfloor \mod{10} 
   $$

How can we move further to determine the $100$th decimal place of the expression?

Comment: $(3+\sqrt{10})^{1000}$ is the integer $2a_{1000}$ minus the tiny number $(3-\sqrt{10})^{1000}$. That tiny number is so tiny that the part of $(3+\sqrt{10})^{1000}$ to the right of the decimal point will begin with many nines. You may want to try to prove that in fact it begins with more than one hundred nines.

Comment: Thanks @Gerry Myerson !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $\sqrt{10}-3<0.2$, so $(\sqrt{10}-3)^{1000}<0.2^{1000}=5^{-1000}<10^{-500}$, so it starts with more than $500$ zeroes. Since $(\sqrt{10}+3)^{1000}=2a_{1000}-(\sqrt{10}-3)^{1000}$, its first $500$ decimal places are just $9$s.

Comment: Thanks @Martund !

Comment: Much as I suggested.

Comment: Yes, @GerryMyerson, it is motivated from your comment.